# PDF-Pages To PNG And Back To PDF In A Hotfolder Via Script

Tags: sorting, filenames, pdftk

For security-reasons I want to decompose PDF-files and put them back together (*like printing them and scanning them back in*). I want to offer this for my users, so I would like to script a kind of hotfilder-solution. While writing this question, I almost figured it out myself. There is just one glitch: convert (*the command to convert one pdf-file into many png-pages*) names the output-files without leading zeros. pdftk (*command to combine pdf-pages in order to create one pdf-document*) sorts files differently, so my newly composed pdf is like this:
page 1
page 10
page 100
page 11
page 12
page 2

Can you help me with that?

Here is my script so far:

```
SETLOCAL
CHCP 1252
SET WORKFOLDER=C:\Users\myself\Documents
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKFOLDER%" MD "%WORKFOLDER%"
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKFOLDER%\png" MD "%WORKFOLDER%\png"


:get_filenames
C:
CD "%WORKFOLDER%"
FOR %%X IN (*.pdf) DO (
convert -density 300 -quality 100 "%%~nX.pdf" "%WORKFOLDER%\png\%%~nX.png"
CD "%WORKFOLDER%\png%
mogrify -format pdf *.png
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "%WORKFOLDER%\png\*.pdf" cat output "%WORKFOLDER%\%%~nX_sicher.pdf"
)
```

Comment: I could probably extract all pdf-pages BEFORE converting them into png. Maybe that would fix the sorting. But then I would have to use a for-loop in a for-loop (for all pdf-files do extract pdf pages and for all pdf pages convert them into png) and this is making me headaches right now. Anyway splitting pdf BEFORE converting would be <pdftk "%input%\*.pdf" burst>.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43135727/batch-add-leading-zeroes-filename

Answer (score 0):

fixed it somehow. May not be elegant, but it's working. Here is the code. Suggestions to make this smoother are welcome.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
CHCP 1252
SET WORKFOLDER=C:\Users\Myself\Documents
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKFOLDER%" MD "%WORKFOLDER%"
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKFOLDER%\png" MD "%WORKFOLDER%\png"
C:
CD "%WORKFOLDER%"
FOR %%X IN (*.pdf) DO (
convert -density 300 -quality 100 "%%~nX.pdf" "%WORKFOLDER%\png\output_%%02d_%%.png"
CD "%WORKFOLDER%\png"
mogrify -format pdf *.png
CD "%WORKFOLDER%"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" "%WORKFOLDER%\png\*.pdf" cat output "%WORKFOLDER%\%%~nX_secure.new"
RENAME "%%~nX.pdf" "%%~nX.org"
DEL "%WORKFOLDER%\png\*.*" /F /S /Q
GOTO start1
)

CD "%WORKFOLDER%"
RENAME *.org *.pdf
RENAME *.new *.pdf

PAUSE
```

One could also compress/optimize the output-pdfs with something like this (not working yet):

```
FOR %%X IN (*.pdf) DO (
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="%%~nX_komprimiert.pdf" "%%~nX.pdf"
)
```